# Postman not receiving response to NodeJS Express Post request

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, post, postman

Here's the relevant part of the NodeJscode:

```
app.post("/makeSentenceParamsPost", express.json(), (request, response) => {
  const object    = request.body.object;
  const adjective = request.body.adjective;
    
  console.log('<br>POST requestuest received: object = ' + object + '; adjective = ' + adjective >'<br>>');

  let sentence = softwareUnderTest.MakeAsentence(object, adjective);
  sentence = JSON.stringify(sentence);
  response.set( sentence );
})
```

Here's a screenshot, breakpointed at the penultimate line, after the call to `softwareUnderTest.MakeAsentence`:

[image]

So, the request made it to my code, and `MakeAsentence` did what it ought to.

Here's a screenshot, breakpointed at the last line, `response.set`:

[image]

when I continue, or run without breakpoints, Postman never receives a response :-(

I am running a Nodejs Express server in Visual Studio Code. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: dont you have any errors?

Comment: Nothing. In fact, if I do introduce an error into my code, then Postman gets an immediate response. Maybe I need to set more headers for postman to accept the response?

Comment: shouldnt it be `.send`  instead?

Comment: We have a winner !!  Yes, it should (and I am an idiot). Feel free to post that as the answer

Answer (score 3):

As i read your image i see you do not actually send te response.

```
// Set the response type eg. HTML or JSON
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(JSON.stringify(sentence));
```

Also please don't add pictures to your question as it is hard to read on small devices and we can't copy your code to test it...

This is some code of one of my API's, maybe that helps.

```
// I use "express": "^4.17.2"
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        status: "success",
        timestamp: Date.now(),
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks (and upvote). I did not know about setting content type in the response (should it no be `text/json`? In any case, neither gives me a response. But, if I put an error into my code, I get an immediate response. Maybe I need more headers for Postman to accept it? Apologies for the images. They just seemed the quickest way to show things, without posting the entire code. I will avoid images in future. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Does your application show the `console.log()`? I will add some example code of one of my API's. maybe you can use that.

Comment: Yes, I see the console log. A GET request also does not work :-(  Oh, wait, it does when I use your code. I will tweak mine & post it when it works. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Try this response: `res.status(200).json(sentence);`

Comment: That will work. As pointed out in a comment above, I was calling `set` instead of `send`. D'oh !!

Comment: I am still totally stuck with POST. It works from Postman, but not from Mocha :-(

Comment: Please show your mocha testcase

Comment: I poste da new question for it. This problem was just calling `set` in stead of `send`.  New problem is that my code handles POST request from Poatman, but not from Moha. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153886/encoding-json-post-data-in-mocah-test-of-nodejs-express-code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242102/discussion-between-menno-spijker-and-mawg-says-reinstate-monica).